# C Struct Order of Members

Tags: c, struct

I'm taking over a piece of code..c programming in linux.  I did a small change to a struct

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int a1;
  ..
  ..
  ..
  float f1;
  unsigned int a2;
  unsigned int a3;

  unsigned int offending; // shifted this
} test;
```

I shifted unsigned int offending to before float f1, like this:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int a1;
  ..
  ..
  ..
  unsigned int offending;
  float f1;
  unsigned int a2;
  unsigned int a3;


} test;
```

and the code crashes... what could be the problem?

Is the order of members of a c struct important?

Comment: Whether or not that changes the in-memory layout of the struct is implementation-dependent. If you have another piece of code that's looking, say, 64 bits into the struct for something, it's now getting data it doesn't expect. Is this linked to by another piece of software that didn't get recompiled? Or is this standalone. Also, depending on the implementation, that may end up changing the total size of the type if it screws up the alignment the compiler was using.

Comment: "what could be the problem?" - the problem with your code or the problem your experiencing? The former we cannot answer since we see none except a structure typedef. The latter is likely because you changed your layout without understanding how it is used throughout your code, and failed to account for something (Ex: a binary structure read from disk of previous saved data with the old layout, a socket from a client/server compiled with the old version unaware of the new version, etc).

Comment: Agree with comments above. If your make file does not have the proper dependencies, it might fail to recompile files that depend on this struct.

Comment: The whole crashing code should be included into the question otherwise we don't know what can be causing the problem.

Comment: It is important to understand that while you normally don't make use of `struct + offset` to access members of a struct, there are a lot of data structures that do. Especially in structures like linked-lists that employ void types for generic implementations. There the order of members in the struct are critical. Changing the order in that case it is easy to see how it could lead to a crash.

Comment: Hi, I realised that the code was receiving data from a python script that hard coded the struct variables (in the original order). Changing the order in the script solved the issue. Sorry I couldn't post more as the code is sensitive.

Comment: @Bandrami the items in the struct must be laid out in memory in the same order that they were declared. (There could be padding of course). So it is guaranteed that the struct layout is changed in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What could be the problem? Depend on the rest of the code, and what else you did.

No, the order of members of a struct is not intrinsically important. It is made so when other code depends on it.

Possible causes (not exhaustive):

- You didn't recompile everything and there is external linkage on this struct or some aspect of it.
- By moving the member you changed the alignment of other members and/or the sizeof() the struct, and didn't compensate for that.
- There is a literal constant or macro somewhere with a size or offset that depends on this struct.
- There is faulty code which never failed before but does now because of a change in memory layout.
- The struct is used somewhere as part of another struct or union, and the problem is related to that.
- There is a list initialisation using {} that no longer matches the member order.

You really should provide details of how it crashes. Otherwise it guesswork. And perhaps even then.

edit: ht @Jens.

Comment: Later code makes use of `struct + offset` to access the members of the struct now gets `unsigned int offending` instead of `float f1`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Did I not cover that with 'literal constant or macro...offset'? What other case did you have in mind?

Comment: Well, no (at least I didn't initially snap to it). I was thinking about the generic linked-list implementation that rely on the struct address + offset for member access. That didn't fall into the constant or macro language of your third point as I initially read it. (re-reading it, I see that the literal constant, as you write, would be the offset specified) Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for crashes if you change data layout is initialization. If you have old-time initializers in your code that use declaration order, all of a sudden the fields will receive different values than before. Therefore modern C since C99 has *designated initializers* that avoid that problem:

```
test toto = { 32, ... , 42, };                    // sensible to reordering
test tata = { .a1 = 32, ... , .offending = 42, }; // still the same
```